# How to loop through UIElement in a List<UIElement>?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, uielement

I have a List that contains a `Canvas` which contains also some `UIElement` as follow:

```
List<Canvas> cvList = new List<Canvas>();
Canvas cv = new Canvas();
cv.Width = 100;
cv.Height = 100;
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Content = "OK";
cv.Children.Add(btn);
cvList.Add(cv);
```

The array size of `Canvas` is dynamic and immmutable, which is the reason I use List instead of `Array`.

My question is if I were to modify properties of one `UIElement` (i.e. Button.Content), how could I access the `Button` properties? If it was an Array I could simply loop through the array and find an index that matches, like below:

```
Canvas[] cv = new Canvas[myInt];
Button[] btn = new Button[myInt];
for (int i = 0; i<myInt; i++)
{
cv[i] = new Canvas();
btn[i] = new Button();
btn[i].Content = "OK";
cv[i].Children.Add(btn[i]);
}
btn[5].Content = "Not OK";
```

but how could I do so for an UIElement that is in a List?

```
List<UIElement>[int].UIElement.Properties
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do it the exact same way. You can loop through and find the index that matches.

```
foreach (Canvas c in cvList) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Comment: but how do I access the Button inside the Canvas? Do I have to do a foreach loop for each UIElement I want to change its properties?

Comment: You access the button inside the canvas the same way you would if the canvas were in an array -- for example, `Button btn = c.Children.OfType<Button>().First();`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work on lists as well as arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i<myInt; i++)
{
    cv[i].Content = "Hello";
}
```